# "required namespace never provided" when ClojureScript file is in different folder

Tags: heroku, clojure, clojurescript

I have a basic Chestnut project folder, with the `src/cljs` folder set up like so:

```
cljweb
- algorithms
  - gen-prob.cljs
- core.cljs
- webpage.cljs
```

In `gen-prob.cljs`, I have this namespace:

```
(ns cljweb.algorithms.gen-prob)
```

And in `webpage.cljs`, I'm requiring `gen-prob.cljs` like so:

```
(ns cljweb.webpage
  (:require [cljweb.algorithms.gen-prob :as prob]))
```

This all seems correct, however when I compile it to Heroku (`git push heroku master`), I get this error:

```
remote:        SEVERE: /tmp/build_c25e7d304d366857019ddcc3f177f680/target/cljweb/webpage.js:7: 
ERROR - required "cljweb.algorithms.gen_prob" namespace never provided
remote:        goog.require('cljweb.algorithms.gen_prob');
remote:        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When I open the Heroku app (`heroku open`), nothing is displayed, and I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cljweb is not defined
```

Here is the Heroku website:

```
murmuring-brook-22851.herokuapp.com
```

And you can clone it using:

```
$ heroku git:clone -a murmuring-brook-22851
```

And renaming the whole folder to `cljweb`.

Answer (score 1):

Dashes from namespace names need to be replaced with underscore in the file name. You need to change `gen-prob.cljs` filename to `gen_prob.cljs` as the error message suggests:

> required "cljweb.algorithms.gen**_**prob" namespace never provided

Comment: Did you try running it locally? How do you run it on Heroku? Please, show your `project.clj` file.

Comment: The error's gone, but Heroku still doesn't load properly - the generated Javascript is awkwardly cut off. I think this is a separate issue from the actual namespace thing. [Here](https://hastebin.com/xujupurafo.lisp)'s a hastebin file of `project.clj`.

Comment: Did you run your app locally in the same way as on Heroku? Is it working? Try to isolate the issue so you are sure if it's related to Heroku or to the build itself. How do you run your application on Heroku? What's your Procfile?

Comment: I provided a link where you should be able to clone everything through Heroku in my question. Does the link not work?

Comment: "You do not have access to the app murmuring-brook-22851". I am trying to suggest what you can check - did you check it? Did you bother to see if it works correctly locally?

Comment: Yes, it works correctly locally (tested using Figwheel). My laptop is out of battery right now, I'm writing this on my phone. Sorry for the trouble.